# Release the click after amount of drag

Tags: java, javafx

Is there a way after the user presses the left click and drag something, after some amount of time or condition to release the left click? I don't want to consume the event, also if I disable the node the press is still there and the drag is still going, nor I want to remove the event, because another event is dependent on it. I just want the node to be released from the left click press.

Comment: Is this for a bot?